# Raspi 4 with Noetic & 64bit compatible?

Tags: rasbperrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to run Noetic on a 64bit RPi Ubuntu/Focal server version, but the following error does occur:

```
$ uname -a
Linux robot 5.4.0-1033-raspi #36-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Thu Mar 25 19:00:51 UTC 2021 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux

$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver 'hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80' --recv-key C1CF6E31E6BADE8868B172B4F42ED6FBAB17C654
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.wGbRJBPKZs/gpg.1.sh --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-key C1CF6E31E6BADE8868B172B4F42ED6FBAB17C654
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No keyserver available
```

Any idea why this is not working? On the installation page, the aarch64 architecture is only listed for arch/experimental. But I have read plenty of blogs which mentioned that this setup would work. Any hint? Thx a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/376080/raspi-4-with-noetic-&-64bit-compatible?/) by [ticotico](https://answers.ros.org/users/58821/ticotico/) on ROS Answers with karma: 212 on 2021-04-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved it thanks to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/510464/416400) answer.
Summarizing it here for convenience:

> Add the following line to `/etc/resolv.conf`
>
> ```
> nameserver 8.8.8.8 # Google dns
> ```

Cheers!

---

Originally posted by [ticotico](https://answers.ros.org/users/58821/ticotico/) with karma: 212 on 2021-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-04-21**:
Seems like a work-around to me, but if you're happy, we're happy.